# How to spawn a reverse shell?

Tags: powershell

I'm using a linux virtual box on windows computer. I want to connect to the windows PowerShell, but I can't find out how. I found this cheat sheet: https://github.com/swisskyrepo/PayloadsAllTheThings/blob/master/Methodology%20and%20Resources/Reverse%20Shell%20Cheatsheet.md
(Commands I used are at the bottom of the page).
I used the first command to set a listener. I used netstat command to make sure it's listening and it is. Then I put the second command in my PowerShell on windows and it said that the fully interactive shell was spawned. But after a few seconds it faild with error message:

```
ConPtyShellException: [-] ConPtyShellException: WSAConnect failed with error code: 10060
   at ConPtyShell.connectRemote(String remoteIp, Int32 remotePort)
   at ConPtyShell.SpawnConPtyShell(String remoteIp, Int32 remotePort, UInt32 rows, UInt32 cols, String commandLine, Boolean upgradeShell)
   at ConPtyShellMainClass.ConPtyShellMain(String[] args)
```

Also the listener didn't pick up anything. Maybe I was using the wrong ip address? Should I use the private one insted of the public address? I'm not sure what to do, any ideas?

Comment: Wouldn't a remote shell be enough for a local VM to connect to the host? Install Powershell core in Linux and do pssession https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/running-remote-commands?view=powershell-7.2#start-an-interactive-session

Comment: This seems like a good idea, but you need administrative rights to do so. I was hoping there would be a more efficient way of doing this so I could connect on other computers too without having too run it as administrator.

Comment: You are right for default configuration, but you can change it with `Set-PSSessionConfiguration` as described here: 
 https://4sysops.com/archives/powershell-remoting-without-administrator-rights/

Comment: The reverse shell examples there work perfectly fine, probably you didn't change the ip address and port for the ones of the listening host. Also this github has some other good ones https://github.com/samratashok/nishang